# ZedGraph on resize?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

How can I access the event that is triggered when a graph pane is resized?

After each resize, I want to fix the text size on the title and labels so they don't get huge when the window is maximized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can subscribe for `ZedGraphControl`'s resize event:

```
zg1.Resize += new EventHandler(zg1_Resize);
```

But it's easier to achieve what you want by disabling the automatic font scaling on the GraphPane:

```
zg1.MasterPane[0].IsFontScaled = false;
```

If you have more than one GraphPane on your MasterPane, use:

```
 foreach(GraphPane pane in zg1.MasterPane.PaneList)
    pane.IsFontScaled = false;
```

See also:
http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=How_does_the_font_and_chart_element_scaling_logic_work%3F 
http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/P_ZedGraph_PaneBase_IsFontsScaled.htm